# Creating php DLL from pecl source files

Tags: php, pecl

How can i build a DLL file from a PECL source file.

I need to build DLL for APC extension from PECL source (http://pecl.php.net/package/APC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. download php_apc-3.1.9-svn20110915-5.3-VC9-x64-win7-2008.zip from http://www.mediafire.com/php-win64-extensions
2. Enable the APC extension in your PHP.INI file.
   Edit the php.ini file and add the following line in the extensions section:
   extension = php_apc.dll
3. Restart apache / iis and look at the output of phpinfo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux life is easy :) The `pecl` command does the work for you. It will download the sources, compile them and install the extension.

On Linux type in your terminal as root:

```
pecl install apc
```

After installation you should make sure that your php.ini contains the line

```
extension=apc.so
```

But when reading your post (you tell about dll) I have to assume that you are using Windows. I've never compiled a PHP extension on Windows. But you may start [here](http://php.net/manual/de/install.windows.building.php) to investigate.

Before trying to compile for myself **I would try to find a precompiled** windows apc.dll for your PHP version. You can find some [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/). You'll just have to download the extension and place it in your PHP extension folder. Then you'll have to add the following line to your php.ini:

```
extension=apc.dll
```